# Code behind/beside Model (.cs-aspx.cs-aspx) VS MVC model, what is the difference really?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, design-patterns

What are the basic differences between classic .cs-aspx.cs-aspx (code behind/beside) model and new MVC model?

Comment: I don't really understand what you are asking?

Answer (score 5):

The basic difference between MVC and classic ASP is that in classic ASP all of the code  and mark-up for the application exists in the .asp file.  In MVC the .aspx file contains only the code and mark-up for rendering the page.  The rest of the application for handling requests, retrieving model data, and enforcing business logic exists in controller and model classes.  These classes can be much more easily tested than class ASP code because it is separated from the code that is responsible for rendering the view.

This separation of concerns is the basis of the [MVC pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model-view-controller).  According to the pattern, the code is divided into three major components -- Model, View, and Controller.  Classes in the model represent the business objects for the application, the persistence framework, and business logic applied to the business objects.  Classes in the controller accept incoming requests, use the inputs or query parameters to retrieve the appropriate model data, and generate the necessary data for the view to render.  Views (aspx pages) take the data supplied by the controller and generate the mark up.

Webforms (codebehind) is somewhere between classic ASP and the MVC pattern.  Webforms does not enforce the separation of concerns in the way that MVC does, but it does allow much more of the code to exist "behind" the actual page.  For example, you can separate out the business objects, business logic, and persistence framework (the Model, if you will) from the code that is responsible for generating the view.  The difficulty is that the controller actions (input handling and model retrieval) are still linked with the view rendering code.  This integration makes it much more difficult to test this code and makes the view/controller code much more dependent on each other than is necessary -- the concerns are "mixed", not "separated."  In general, this is evidence of bad design because it make it more difficult to make needed changes in the future.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Well, i knew what the difference was b/w classic asp and MVC or classic ASP and code behind model. It seems like MVC Model (Java Practice) is somewhat another name that microsoct also followed replacing the existing code behind model: 
Controler = code behind file, view = aspx file, model=class.cs

Comment: No.  Codebehind != controller since the codebehind directly interacts with the view components.  This is what makes it hard to test.

Answer (score 1):

Simply put it this way: MVC is how really web apps should be built. Code-behind (asp.net web forms) is not a good practice. If you are truly a developer you will appreciate that the MVC is the best practice since it really separates logic from data and presentation. Simply MVC is the elegant and right way.

Answer (score 0):

A really simple way to perceive the difference between MVC and ASP (or ASP.NET forms for that matter) is that in MVC the Controller is the handler of the request.

Requests get routed to a controller not a 'page' or a 'form'.  The controller will pass along info in the request to the model then make some simple choices as to which view that should be used to present the desired state of the model.  Note this is the important point the controller has a choice of what view to use in the response.

MVC breaks the relationship between the requested URL and the UI code needed to render a particular representation of data.